# How to get the event that used to drawing the system scrollbar of the control?

Tags: winforms, scrollbar

I can able to add the System Scrollbars to the control, by overriding the CreateParams property and then add the style for showing the system scrollbar as below,

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, UnmanagedCode = true)]
    get
    {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.Style = (cp.Style | WindowMessages.WS_HSCROLL);
        cp.Style = (cp.Style | WindowMessages.WS_VSCROLL);        
        return cp;
    }
}
```

Its provides the support for showing the system scrollbars in my control. How can i get the drawing event of those added system scrollbars.

Or is there any way to get the size and location of the visible system scrollbars on the control.

Comment: There are no "drawing events", pretty unclear why you think you need them.  Do consider that you are doing this the Hard Way, simply changing the base class of your control to Panel or ScrollableControl or UserControl gives you scrollbar support for free.

Comment: Hi Hans, Thanks for your suggestion. I need to change the default drawing colors of the Thumb and back color of the scroll bar.

Answer (score 1):

Hans Passant already mentioned that you're enabling scrollbars the hard way but what you're looking for is not doable with the default scrollbar anyway.

The scrollbars in Windows Forms applications are not provided by .NET Framework. They're fully drawn by Windows and there's no way for you to change the colors by conventional means. What you need to do instead, is hide the default scrollbars and replace them with custom ScrollBar controls that support styling.

Here's an old but good tutorial on how to skin scrollbars in Windows Forms applications: [How to skin scrollbars for Panels, in C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14801/How-to-skin-scrollbars-for-Panels-in-C)

And here you can see the result:

[image]